# Routing config issue cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Given this URL's

```
http://localhost:51095/Person  // This is equivalent to this one Person/Index
http://localhost:51095/Person/Allan
```

I setup a route config for it as follows :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Person",
    "Person/{personName}",
    new { controller = "Person", action = "Person", personName = UrlParameter.Optional }
    )
;

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

First URL should follow the `Default` route and the second should follow the `Person` route.

This is not working because the first config seems to catch all these URL's

Comment: Remove `personName = UrlParameter.Optional` But this is likely to cause other issues if you have any action methods in `PersonController` except `Index()` and `Person()` unless you create a specific route for all the other methods

Comment: @StephenMuecke exactly, but how can I do that? Should I use `Route` annotation? My plan is to apply only the rule in specific action but some methods get affected.

Comment: That might depend on what other methods are in `PersonController`. Is changing it say `/People/Allan` an option?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is remove `personName = UrlParameter.Optional` in the first Route. This would allow only urls that provide a `personName` value to access this Route. If no value is provided, it should fall through to the default Route.

But you'd want to think about the future with this strategy: if you implement new actions on that Person controller, you'd need to add a new Route for each of them. If you had a new 'Edit' action for example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Person_Edit",
"Person/Edit/{personName}",
new { controller = "Person", action = "Edit" }
)
```

You'd want to add these new Routes **before** the first one though - ordering/precedence of Routes is important.

Comment: got the idea, I'm planning to add a MVC 5 routing in my actions